# How can I safely store a password in source code?

Tags: c#

I would like to store a password to an online service in my application, to which I occasionally transfer log data. My question is how I can store the password in the code in a relatively secure way, so that it is difficult to find it out by reverse engineering. What are the preferred procedures?

EDIT: The user does not enter any password. The password is fixed, let's say `password123` and I have to use that password to login to an online service to transfer data in a way that the user cannot gain this password trough reverse engineering. Is there a way not to hardcode it and hide it somehow in the code?

Comment: The password can be sniffed when client communicate with online service or you secured somehow this communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should not be storing the password in your source code which runs on client machine.

For this type of scenario, still you can avoid hard coding by retrieving the password from server using some `API` calls after performing the required authentication/ authorization.

If you store the password in the code running on the client side, whatever you do like obfuscation/ encryption/ encoding, it can still be extracted using reverse engineering.

**Edit:**

> Thick client - all logic is on client side. No hosting server. It
>   would be exaggerated to rent a server just for protecting my email
>   password. Is there really no other solution? How is connection string
>   to database then secured in other applications against reverse
>   engineering?

As mentioned above you can't completely secure it, but you can make it tough to break, for that you can try following steps.

1. Encrypt your password.
2. Store the encryption key in multiple parts in different location,
   like one part in code file, one part in configuration file and one
   part in user registry.
3. Obfuscate your code.

Comment: If you can clarify how to use  hash of a password as "a password to an online service" that would be an answer...

Comment: What is he going to do with a hashed password on the client? He can't revert it back to a password. What's is going to send to the server? A hash?

Comment: @Dmitry, no one should be able to revert the hash back to password.

Comment: Ok, then what do you send to the server for authentication?

Comment: You should send the password entered by the user to the server, generate the hash and compare it with stored hash. (hash to hash comparison)

Comment: That's not what the question was. He never wrote that users have accounts. He just want a password to send logs to a log server.

Comment: @Dmitry I now understand your point. I’ll update the answer appropriately

Comment: @PSK Is there a code example how to do that?

Comment: what is the technology you are using for your application?

Comment: It is just a simple game in C#. No database queries. The password is for sending logs via email.

Comment: I meand is it thick client, web based, console? Do you have any hosting server where you can expose your services/APIs?

Comment: Thick client - all logic is on client side. No hosting server. It would be exaggerated to rent a server just for protecting my email password. Is there really no other solution? How is connection string to database then secured in other applications against reverse engineering?

Comment: @Bob, i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a String and you want it to be hidden when it comes to reverse engineering.

I recommend to hash your String(Password) with MD5 algorithm and store the hash in your source code and only compare the hashed result of entered password with your stored one.

**According to the comments** :

MD5 turn out to be not good enough for encryption!

Take a look at [this](https://coderwall.com/p/4puszg/c-convert-string-to-md5-hash) link.

Comment: MD5 was cracked like 20 years ago.

Comment: Read about lookup tables and rainbow tables. BTW 128-bit hash has been cracked 2 weeks ago in 11 minutes using 3 GF RTX 2080 GPUs. And yes- SALT was there.

Comment: MD5 is only useful if you want to check the integrity of data, i.e. to check if data was non-maliciously altered by transmission errors and the like. It should never be used for security purposes.

Comment: @Dmitry wow! I didn’t know! Thanks, at least is it still good for the purpose of question?